# How to render an ngTable without the pagination decorations?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ngtable

In my small AngularJS app, I render several tables using the ngTable library.  Only one could use pagination.  The others will always fit on less than a page.  Every rendered ngTable seems to add the "10 25 50 100" selector below the table.  For most of my tables, this is wasted space and is nonfunctional.  How can I remove that section and get that space back?

Answer (score 57):

This was recently fixed (https://github.com/esvit/ng-table/issues/6) This code should do it for you (copied from same git issue):

```
$scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
    count: items.length // hides pager
},{
    counts: [] // hides page sizes
});
```

Comment: Interesting.  I managed to find a completely different solution.  For each table that I don't want pagination, I just added 'template-pagination="nopager"' where "nopager" refers to an empty script block.  This is more along the lines of presentation logic only being in the presentation.  Can you compare these two solutions?

Comment: I would say my proposed one is slightly cleaner, but that's preference and style more than anything.. I would also guess that my proposed one is slightly faster, since yours will actually do all the compile/link stuff for an empty block and try to inject it. That said, it would be a negligible perf. improvement.

Comment: I tried this, looked clean, but it didn't work for me, I ended up with:

.ng-table-pager {
    display: none;
}

Comment: `ngTableParams` takes two arguments: baseParameters and baseSettings, in that order. Each are JSON objects. So make sure you are putting your `counts: []` in the baseSettings and not the other.  Like so:  `new ngTableParams({baseParameters}, {counts:[]});`

Comment: This is giving performance issue and slowing down the loading of page as it is loading the entire data in a single page

Answer (score 12):

Use this approach (based on this [link](https://github.com/esvit/ng-table/issues/6)) :

```
$scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
        page: 1,   // show first page
        count: 5  // count per page
    }, {
        counts: [], // hide page counts control
        total: 1,  // value less than count hide pagination
        getData: function($defer, params) {
            $defer.resolve(data);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

You could hide it with css:

```
.ng-table-pager {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Override your table declaration by including the attribute template-pagination="custom/pager"  This allows you to add pagination around your table, or not include at all.

. . .

Comment: While it indeed hides the template, it also generates a call to the server, resulting in a 404 (if there no page returned).

Answer (score 2):

```
$scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
    noPager: true // hides pager
},{
    ...
});
```

after many tries, this method helps me. You can find the condition of pagination control's ng-show is "!noPager" in your dev console.

Comment: This did not work for me, not sure whether this is version specific. I would prefer this way as it is a more obvious property to set. Will stick with @David M. Karr's solution for now

Comment: As of v4 (and maybe earlier versions) this does not work. pager.html has this line: `ng-if="params.data.length` for displaying the pager.

Comment: Hi, @DanMorphis . The answer was written in 2015 when the version of Angular was very old. I have not written Angular for a very long time. So the answer may not work any more. ^_^

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, CSS to only hide the pagination immediately following the table:

```
table.ng-table + div[ng-table-pagination]{
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.
I called NgTableParams of gridParams 
and after load data I put

```
gridParams.total(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, very basic using style="display:none".

```
<mat-paginator style="display:none" [length]="recordCount" [pageSize]="pageSize"></mat-paginator>
```